# pyGTK Multiple line input fields?

Tags: python, pygtk

Already searched on google... doesnt seem to be there... help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/sec-TextViews.html

http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtktextview.html

Comment: Bit of a confusing name, isn't it?

Comment: "View" here is in the [Model-View-Controller](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Model%E2%80%93View%E2%80%93Controller) sense.